# changing font-family on the page is not always working

Tags: jquery, html, css, fonts, bootstrap-form-helper

I am a feature which allows user to change font-family of text inside divs and it kind of works. I will try to explain what is wrong hopefully you will understand.

User clicks on font and select "Arial Black"
Click on div, font changes.
User clicks on "Times New Roman"
Click on div, font changes.
User clicks on google font "Lato"
Click on div, font changes.
User clicks on font "Arial Black"
Click on div, nothing happens (I did console.log and both font and font2 are undefined at this point).
It only starts to work again when user selects "Arial" and click on div.

```
var originalFont = $('#fonts1').data('font');
            var originalgFont = $('#googlefonts1').data('font');
            var originalsFont = $('#fontsizes1').data('fontsize');
            var originalColor = $('#colorChoice').css('background', 'white');
            var textColor =$('#textColor').css('color', 'black');
            var font;
            $("#fonts1").on("change", function() {
                font = $(this).val();
            });
            $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function() {
                $(this).css('font-family', font);
                console.log(font);
                font = originalFont;
            });
            var font2;
            $("#googlefonts1").on("change", function() {
                font2 = $(this).val();
            });
            $("#content-link2").on("click", "*", function() {
                $(this).css('font-family', font2);
                console.log(font2);
                font2 = originalgFont;
            });


<button style="display: none" onclick="$('#fonts1').bfhfonts({font: 'Arial'})" id="fontsShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all">Load Fonts</button>
        <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all" id="fontsHide">Hide Fonts</button>
        <select title="Choose a font and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="fonts1" class="form-control margin hide_all"></select>

        <button style="display: none" onclick="$('#googlefonts1').bfhgooglefonts({font: 'Lato'})" id="googleShow" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all">Google fonts</button>
        <button style="display: none" class="btn btn-primary form-control margin hide_all" id="googleHide">Hide Google</button>
        <select title="Choose a font and then click on any box" style="display: none" id="googlefonts1" class="form-control margin hide_all"></select>
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle, that will help to approach the issue in convenient way.

Comment: Well, the select is generated using a library, could have a look at the website using developer tools if I give you the address?

Comment: Sure, please tell me the address.

Comment: https://www.webuilder.co.uk/template

Comment: @vijaymishra click on the pink template on left and then go Edit>Load Fonts, if you play around with normal and google fonts you will realise there is an issue

Comment: Did you try to resolve the error in console first? There is something replace of undefined, try resolving that first. Then it may work.

Comment: Nope, that issue appeared recently and it was not working before either even when that error wasn't there so it's definetely not related, to be fair I don't know what it is refering to because I don't have anything with 'replace' it points me to jquery library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137425/discussion-between-vijay-mishra-and-przemek).